How can I save an image to a tab view and not for all tabviews?
I am SUPER new to iOS development, and I have a basic app wireframe developed. I am scratching my head at this one (and to be honest, I'm not a great coder yet, but I'm trying). Basically, I have a screen where you can add multiple tabviews:
Tab View with Two Tabs
When you click choose pit photo, you can choose a photo or take a picture and that becomes the picture on the tab. Unfortunately, it changes the picture on ALL tabs.
Basically, I am trying to insert the picture into the TabItem structure so that it's part of the tab and not all the tabs.
Note: When I first add the tab, I have a default image in there. In order to change it on one tab, you have to select a new photo.
Here is the code I have so far----it may be slightly in flux but I want to somehow add the image to the tab and not always take the picture I select and put it on all of the tabs:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TabItem: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let name: String
  let image: UIImage
    
}

final class DynamicTabViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabItems: [TabItem] = []
    @Published var tabCount = 1
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    

    
    func addTabItem() {
       // tabItems.append(TabItem(name: " Tab \(tabCount)", image: image))
       // tabItems.append(TabItem(name: " Tab \(tabCount)", image: "0\(tabCount).square"))
        tabItems.append(TabItem(name: " Tab \(tabCount)", image: UIImage(named: "IMG_7878")!))
        tabCount += 1
        
    }
    
    func removeTabItem() {
        if tabItems.isEmpty{
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            tabItems.removeLast()
            tabCount -= 1
        }
    }
    func updateTabPic() {

        //update current tabs picture
        //tabItems.append(TabItem(name: " Tab \(tabCount)", image: UIImage))
        

    }
}


class imagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    
    init(image: Binding<UIImage?>, isShown:Binding<Bool>){
        _image = image
        _isShown = isShown
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            image = uiImage
            isShown = false
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
    
    
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController
    typealias Coordinator = imagePickerCoordinator
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        //update array to have image
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return imagePickerCoordinator(image: $image, isShown: $isShown)
        //I think I have to somehow call the update tab pic here and pass it the image OR i need to do it in the func imagePickerController
        
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
}




And help, suggestions, etc. would be super appreciated. I need to be steered into the right direction. I'm thinking when I pick the image from the image picture, I need to somehow store it in the current tab Item. I just dont know how to do it in swiftUI.
